# Significance of non-zero cross energy-momentum tensor in Fulling Davies Unruh effect

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime, regularization, unruh-effect

In the *Fulling Davies Unruh effect* We can get the outgoing particle flux from the asymptotic future region $\mathscr{I}^+$ from the mirror trajectory as the following
$$
\mathcal{F}=\int_0^\infty \frac{\omega d\omega}{(e^\frac{2\pi \omega}{a}-1)}
$$
Where $a$ is the acceleration of the mirror. We will get the exact result by calculating the net expectation value of $T_{\mu\nu}$ in $\mathscr{I}^+$ from $\mathscr{I}^-$ and subtracting from the value at $\mathscr{I}^-$ which may be found in Fulling's paper 1976. But if we do not consider the asymptotic case, the net expectation value of $T_{\mu\nu}$ is not zero. So, in this case, the actual particle flux is greater than an asymptotic observer will see. What is the explanation.